# Collaborative Modeling Editor Plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-emf, eclipse-ecf

I need to develop an eclipse plugin for developing Collaborative Modeling Editor.  I have only basic eclipse knowledge.  How can I develop collaborative editors in Eclipse?
Can I use ECF for doing this?

If so, Anyone please give me a hint, how to start with developing Collaborive editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a collaborative diagram editor, you can use the CDO project that provides a collaborative back-end for EMF models. It can handle persistency, conflicts and communication for you. CDO is an official project of the Eclipse Foundation under the EMF category. You can find more about CDO [here](http://www.eclipse.org/cdo/). There is a sub-project of CDO called Dawn that aims at creating a common framework for those who want to build a collaborative tooling for EMF models. It is a framework that can handle most of the work with CDO for you. You should definitively [look at it](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Dawn).

You can find more about Dawn and CDO with their [presentations](http://www.eclipse.org/cdo/documentation/presentations/).

**Disclaimer: I am the leader of an EMF based project of the Eclipse Foundation.**

Comment: This is exactly what I want.  Thanks a lot.  But, I am not sure how I am going to use them as back-end.  Since, I have not used some other projects as a back-end.  Could you please provide some hint for doing this sir?

Comment: With CDO, you can store your EMF models and you have access to APIs to commit changes on a model, update your model with the latest commit, see if there are conflicts etc... You "just" have to build your editor on top of those APIs after that. Dawn "hides" most of those APIs for you. You can start by trying Dawn to see how collaborative editing looks like with CDO here: (http://wiki.eclipse.org/Getting_Started_with_Dawn) Then you can use dawn to build a basic collaborative editor for your need (http://wiki.eclipse.org/Dawn_Codegen). After that you just need to improve the generated code.

Comment: Hi sbegaudeau,  I have successfully used DAWN in my own application.  Now, I need to extend the functionality of DAWN.  How can I do it?  Do u have any idea?